# How to move files with adb shell?

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd, adb, batch-processing

How can I move files with adb shell ?
For example I would like to move SystemUI.apk from /system to /system/app

I didn't find any command to move files inside system partition with adb shell.
Do anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does `mv` not work?

```
mv /system/SystemUI.apk /system/app/
```

Or perhaps you need to be root:

```
su
mv /system/SystemUI.apk /system/app/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:
adb shell mv /system/file_path /sdcard