# Can't move folder in android terminal

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a small backup script, but the mv command in android does not work not like linux.
For example, i execute the following command:

```
adb shell mv  "/system/app/Books/" "/sdcard1/temp/debloat_bkp/system/app/Books/"
```

i get the following error:

```
mv: invalid option -- P
usage: mv [-fiv] source target
       mv [-fiv] source ... directory
mv: /system/bin/cp: terminated with 1 (non-zero) status
```

Have any ideas why i get this error and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be **root** for this `directory/path`, i guess:

```
/system/app/Books/
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18935228/4409113

And that is not a good way though,

**Use:** **[backing up android device using adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225467/backing-up-android-device-using-adb)**

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all
```

Comment: I have root. And start this commnad with root. It is not permission problem. It's seems like I can move only file in Android and can't move folder.

Comment: Yeah well i said that, it's a system folder so, you should use ` cp` or take a look at the the above link.otherwise, if you could do that, perhaps you wil see crashed devices.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error when trying to run:

```
mv system/app/SomeFolder/ ./
```

And I solve it by moving the "SomeFolder" in system/ not in root:

```
mv system/app/SomeFolder/ ./system
```

And you need to have **root** privileges.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

On my odroid + android 5 I can reproduce this with:

```
strace -f mv file_on_one_device /other/device
```

says that *mv* is executing /system/bin/cp with parameters ["mv", "-PRp", "--", "file_on_one_device", "/other/device/" ]. However this *cp* is a softlink to *toolbox*. Because of the first argument (which is *mv*) toolbox thinks it should do a mv. This seems to be a bug in this android 5 toolbox. This is not an issue with udoo + android 6.

My workaround is to do a separate *cp* and *rm* (this is what mv wants to do, but fails)